# Using a std::vector<std::array<T,N>> as a flat contiguous array of T

Tags: c++, arrays, casting, undefined-behavior

A `std::vector` stores its elements contiguously in memory. An `std::array<T,N>` is just a wrapper around `N` contiguous `T` elements, stored directly in the object itself.

Hence I am wondering if a `std::vector<std::array<T,N>>` of size `n` can also be seen as an array of `T` of size `N*n`.

Consider the following code (also [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01b9bc184abc3470)):

```
int main() {
    // init a vector of 10 arrays of 3 elements each
    std::vector<std::array<int,3>> v(10);

    // fill it
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        v[i] = {3*i,3*i+1,3*i+2};
    }

    // take the first array
    std::array<int,3>* a_ptr = v.data();

    // take the first element of the array
    int* i_ptr = a_ptr->data();

    // dereference the pointer for 3*10 elements
    for (int i=0; i<30; ++i) {
        std::cout << i_ptr[i] << ',';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It appears to work for my setup, but is the code legit or is it undefined behavior?

If I were to replace `std::array<int,3>` with a struct:

```
    struct S { 
        int i,j,k;
    };

    std::vector<S> v(10);
    S* s_ptr = v.data();
    int* i_ptr = &S.i;
```

Would it work the same?

What would be the alternatives that would not trigger undefined behavior?

Context: I have a `std::vector<std::array<int,3>>` and I want to serialize it to send it over a network.

Comment: Short answer, no.  We don't know if `std::array` has any padding or any other data members.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think we do: "This container is an aggregate type with the same semantics as a struct holding a C-style array T[N] as its only non-static data member" So it clearly means there is no other data member, and IIUC, no padding either

Comment: @Bérenger `std::array` is still a class type, it isn't an actual array. Implementations can add any padding they want. As far as I can tell, no implementation ever add more padding to `std::array` than it would for an array, but it isn't required. `std::array` is allowed to be larger than an equivalent array. Edit : But even if the sizes happen to be equal, pointer arithmetic doesn't allow this.

Comment: The `struct` solution is definitely not allowed. Even a single `S` can't be treated as a `int[3]`, no `std::vector` required to invalidate the approach.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to iterate the vector this way? You can simply copy the `int` objects into an `int` array of correct size.

Comment: @user17732522 it is an extra copy though...

Comment: @Bérenger I mean, how is this used for serialization? For example, just copying the object representation of the whole array is ok, assuming trivial types and no layout issues. It is specifically the pointer arithmetic that technically has UB.

Comment: @user17732522 Ah I see. The problem is that the library I am using (MPI) takes `void*` arguments, and the underlying array type must be a built-in type. It is does not take a TriviallyCopyable type or the like. But your comment makes me wonder how a TriviallyCopyable object could be copied with `memcopy` without triggering undefined behavior

Comment: @Bérenger `memcpy` is basically magic. The standard says `memcpy` has to be able to do a certain number of things, so it does. Those requirements are not necessarily reflected by what is possible with pointer arithmetic. It's up to standard library implementers to figure it out for their target platform, potentially with compiler support.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Makes sense. It seems to be linked to what Yakk says in his answer: the standard asks for too much magic here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but yes.

No, the C++ standard does not let you treat structs with arrays in them, or even structs with uniform elements, packed together as a single contiguous larger array of the base type.

Yes, in that enough in world production code requires this to work that no compiler is going to break it from working any time soon.

Things to watch out for include packing.  Add static asserts that the size of the structs and arrays is what you expect.  Also, avoid being fancy with object lifetime or going "backwards" from an index besides the first one; the reachability rules of C++ are slightly more likrly to bite you if you do strange things.

Another concern is that these constructs are under somewhat active investigation; the fiasco that std vector cannot be implemented in standard C++, for example, or `std::launder` and `bit_cast`.  When a real standard way to do what you want develops, switching to it might be a good idea, because the old technique will become less likely to be supported.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you point to an isocpp proposal regarding the `std::vector` fiasco?

Comment: I am unaware of a fix to that.  Launder is getting closer.

Answer (score 2):

From a purely pedantic point-of-view, the code has undefined behavior starting with the iteration with `i` equal to `3`:

`i_ptr + 3` points one-past-the-array in the first element of `v` and so you are not allowed to dereference it.

Pointer arithmetic beyond that, i.e. `i_ptr + 4`, has undefined behavior because pointer arithmetic is only allowed inside an array and one-past-the-array.

The `int` arrays of different elements of `v` do not form a larger combined array of `int`s. They cannot be treated as such.

The above holds even if `std::array` has the same size as `int[3]` and therefore has no other padding or members aside from the array.

---

In case of the `struct` version, undefined behavior occurs already when dereferencing `i_ptr + 1`, the one-past-the-object pointer of `v[0].i`.